# How to handle a onClick inside an a element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There are a list of elements like this:

```
    <a href={productPath} target={openInNewTab ? '_blank' : '_self'}>
      <figure>
        <img src={imageBaseUrl() + img} alt={product.title} />
      </figure>
      {isFavorite ? (
        <div className="remove-favorite" onClick={() => deleteCallBack(product.id)}>
         Delete
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </a>
```

but when I want to click on `div` element, but my `href` is clicked.

Comment: Why not add the `onClick` to the anchor instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `stopPropagation()`.

```html
{isFavorite ?
    <div
    className="remove-favorite"
    onClick={
      (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        deleteCallBack(product.id);
      }
    }
  >
    Delete
  </div>
) : null}
```

`stopPropagation` prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action the browser makes on that event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.stopPropagation()

```js
<div className="remove-favorite" onClick={(e) => {
   e.stopPropagation()
   deleteCallBack(product.id)
}}>
   Delete
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add into the link onClick event:

```
onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```